# nginx The page isn’t redirecting properly, how to fix?

Tags: nginx

my nginx conf, goal to make all not https to https, and from www to not www, make by few tutorials by i got this all the time

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> An error occurred during a connection to example.com.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
> accept cookies.

.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri ;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate pathto/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key pathto/privkey.pem;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
 
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate pathto/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key pathto/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate pathto/chain.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /asd/ads/static/;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        alias   /asd/ads/media/;
    }


    location / {

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_redirect off;


    }


}
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: I think your `proxy_pass` is incorrect, try `proxy_pass unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;` (without `http://`)

Comment: @ranisalt if set without http, it gives me 502, if add https the same

Comment: now i left only one server, and got the same, but before i set previoulsy 2 server it was oke, site is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remove from my django settings

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

And it work!!!